# Windows command prompt find specific folder name in sub folders

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-search

Say I have a folder tree such as:

```
C:\Users\Test\My Documents
C:\Users\Test2
C:\Users\Test3\My Documents
```

What command can I run to search through `C:\Users` to check which sub folders have a `My Documents` folder?

So for the above it would come back with:

```
C:\Users\Test\My Documents
C:\Users\Test3\My Documents
```

But not

```
C:\Users\Test2
```

Also, if I wanted to script renaming any sub folders that are found to be called `My Documents` and rename these to just `Documents`, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't `dir /b "My Documents"` work? If not, you can parse it `dir /B | findstr /R /C:"My\sDocuments"`... I guess it would work, I don't have Windows installed here. To rename use `ren`.

Comment: So in this case, you want to rename "Test" to "Documents" or "My Documents" to "Documents"?

Comment: maybe this thread is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271107/bat-file-for-renaming-multiple-folders

Comment: @tumchaaditya I wanted to rename My Documents to Documents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DIR /AD /B "My Documents" /S
```

for listing the folders

Comment: I'll defer to bummi, I forgot the /D switch ;)

Comment: @bummi Thank you! That lists exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Karan It filters the results to directories only, leaving out files.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a vbscript that will also rename the folders for you:

```
Root = INPUTBOX("Please enter the root folder (all subfolders will be renamed)" & vbcrlf & "e.g. C:\TEST")
IF Root="" THEN Canceled

FindStr = INPUTBOX("Please enter the string that you want to find")
IF FindStr = "" THEN Canceled

ReplaceStr = INPUTBOX("Please enter the string that you want to replace it with")
IF ReplaceStr = "" THEN Canceled

SET objFSO= CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

EnumFolders Root

SUB EnumFolders(BYVAL Folder)
    SET objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Folder)
    SET colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders

    FOR EACH objSubfolder in colSubfolders
        NewFolderName = (REPLACE(objSubfolder.name, findstr, replacestr))
            IF NewFolderName <> objSubFolder.Name THEN
                objSubFolder.Name = NewFolderName
            END IF
        enumfolders objSubfolder.path
    NEXT

END SUB

SUB Canceled
    wscript.echo "Script Canceled"
    wscript.quit
END SUB
```

Source: http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_recursive_folder_rename.aspx

**PS: I have not tested this. Please test with an empty directory structure first.**

Comment: its not exactly what he is asking in the question